# Is there resource qualifers in react native similar to android?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Android have resource qualifier to pick appropiate resources based on orientation,screen size and pixel density.Does react native have similar feature.

React native have resource qualifiers such as @1x,@2x... based on pixel density.

Can anyone help me to pick resources based on landscape and screen size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React native does not have such resource qualifiers.